# how to put items in entity classes for multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class

i'm a beginner working with asp.net Entity Framework database first.

There is 2 tables i need to take data from, and 2 class entities which entity framework created already. i have the code below.

```
using (PROJECT_DBEntities context=new PROJECT_DBEntities())
            {
                List<FirstInternship> lst=new List<FirstInternship>();

                lst = context.FirstInternships.SqlQuery("select * from FirstInternships ").ToList<FirstInternship>();

                repeater1.DataSource = lst;
                repeater1.DataBind();
            }
```

This code brings only FirstInternship table items. 
But I have also fields in Student table. So i changed the code like below but dont know how to hold the fields in classes when joining tables.

```
using (PROJECT_DBEntities context=new PROJECT_DBEntities())
            {
                List<FirstInternship> lst=new List<FirstInternship>();

                lst = context.FirstInternships.SqlQuery("select * from FirstInternships f join Students s on s.id=fi.StudentID").ToList<FirstInternship>(); 

                repeater1.DataSource = lst;
                repeater1.DataBind();
            }
```

Here, Do i need to create a third class myself? Or How do i use entity classes if i want to hold multiple table items in classes?  What is the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Entity Framework is an object relational mapper (ORM). It maps relational database entities (say: tables) to objects (as in object oriented entities).

Your `PROJECT_DBEntities` class should contain properties of type `DbSet<T>` by which you can access your model classes (like `FirstInternship`) without writing a single line of SQL. You first code snippet could look like...

```
using (var context = new PROJECT_DBEntities())
{
    // It's useless to initialize the lst variable by a new List

    var lst = context.FirstInternships // No need to write SQL
                     .ToList();        // No need to specify the type

    repeater1.DataSource = lst;
    repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Then in your model classes you will find *navigation properties* like `FirstInternship.Students`. These navigation properties allow you to access associated entities without explicitly writing joins. Not in SQL, not even in LINQ code. It could look like...

```
using (var context = new PROJECT_DBEntities())
{
    var lst = from f in context.FirstInternships
              from s in f.Students
              select new { Internship = f.Name, Sudent = s.Name };
    repeater1.DataSource = lst;
    repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

What follows after `select new` is all up to you. It depends on what you want to show in the repeater. It is recommended to create view model or DTO classes for this purpose:

```
select new StudentDTO { Internship = f.Name, Sudent = s.Name, .... }
```